# Moduli space is a Calabi-Yau manifold?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, projective-geometry, projective-modules, projective-varieties

I asked [a question here where a moduli space of flat connection](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2969548/141334) is related to the $n$-dimensional complex projective space:
$$\Bbb E/S_n \cong \Bbb P^{n-1}. $$ 
This is related to a 4d SU(N) Yang-Mills theory compactified on a 2d 2-torus.

question 1. Do we have some examples where the  moduli space of flat connection are nontrivial **Calabi-Yau** manifolds?

question 2. I also encounter the word moduli space of instantons.

What are the definitions of "moduli space of flat connections" v.s. moduli space of instantons"? What are the differences and their relations?

Comment: Instantons are connections on (bundles over) oriented Riemannian 4-manifolds satisfying $F_A^+ = 0$; that is, the curvature is a self-dual 2-form. Flat connections make sense on any space and any bundle; in differential geometry language they are connections satisfying $F_A = 0$. They are very simple examples of instantons. In the majority examples neither of these are smooth manifolds at all, though it is a beautiful theorem of Kronheimer (and I believe independently Nakajima - I am less familiar with his work) that the space of instantons on $(\Bbb C^2\setminus 0)/\Gamma$ is hyperkahler.

Comment: typo: curvature is an *anti*-self-dual 2-form ($*F_A = -F_A$). and $\Gamma$ in the last sentence is a finite subgroup of $SU(2)$; the instantons there considered need decay conditions on the curvature $F_A$ to form well-behaved moduli spaces (eg the curvature is $L^2$).

Comment: thanks Mike Miller, why dont you compose a deliberate answer then? ;)